# Jupyterlab unresponsive after launching it from within a docker container

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create some python code using a Jupyter Lab instance running within a docker container. I have been able to successfully create the Dockerfile to accomplish the same and launch Jupyterlab on a browser instance. However, as soon as i create a notebook file, the entire lab becomes unresponsive.

Terminal logs:

```
[W 2021-11-20 07:55:33.081 ServerApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 2021-11-20 07:55:33.082 ServerApp] 
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-1-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://444ab754c39e:8888/lab?token=e58757f576973c5a0f88ee76da161cdb79b2cb6962c15109
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=e58757f576973c5a0f88ee76da161cdb79b2cb6962c15109
[W 2021-11-20 07:55:51.654 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
[I 2021-11-20 07:55:58.927 ServerApp] Creating new notebook in 
[I 2021-11-20 07:55:58.978 ServerApp] Writing notebook-signing key to /root/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret
Operation not permitted (bundled/zeromq/src/thread.cpp:309)
qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
Operation not permitted (bundled/zeromq/src/thread.cpp:309)
qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM codait/max-object-detector:arm-arm32v7-latest
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN pip install cmake 
RUN pip install tensorflow keras 
RUN pip install pandas sklearn xgboost pandas-profiling 
RUN pip install jupyter -U && pip install jupyterlab
COPY ./ .
EXPOSE 6006:6006
EXPOSE 8888:888
WORKDIR /home/code
ENTRYPOINT ["jupyter", "lab","--ip=0.0.0.0","--allow-root"]
```

Docker build command:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v local_dir:docker_dir docker_tag
```